# Adding ind labels to a pca biplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, biplot

I'm making a biplot for a PCA, but the individuals are only showing up as points. Is there any way to keep the variables and individuals grouped and have the name label appear over each point? I ask this because it's important to see the groups they belong to, but also to know which individual it is. I'm working with the `fviz_pca_biplot()` function.

I have tried to change the geometry, but when I do, the groups get lost. That's the pca biplot without the labels over every individual.

[image]

Comment: What is your code ? You have a label argument, but by default it should show all labels https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factoextra/versions/1.0.7/topics/fviz_pca

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by adding row names on the original data, which is used to calculate the the PCAs. Also you should add geom on the fviz_biplot() to geom = c("point","text”). As you don’t give the codes, I can’t give you the exact solution.

Comment: Hi Midhun shah, welcome to SO. The thing that makes SO such a valuable resource is the focus on questions that are [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) and answers that can be proven to solve the question at hand. That is why this question has remained unanswered for nine months. While your answer _might_ solve this issue, there is no way to verify it as the OP did not provide enough information. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and familiarise yourself with [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).